# MySQL Docker Compose password not working

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

What I want to do is:

- Create a MySQL8 docker container
- The MySQL container should run a dump file

I was successful in creating the basic container, however, that are several issues:

1. The password that I added in docker-compose.yml is ignored, when I run:

"docker exec -it mysqlDB bash" followed by "MySQL -u admin -p" I get Acess denied, and also with root

2. I don't know if the dump is being used because I can access the DB
3. I'm also getting this error:

[ERROR] [MY-000061] [Server] 1105  Input Output error while reading file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/, line 0, I/O error code 1

I tried many things for hours and it only got worse like not running at all.
I always run with: "docker-compose --log-level DEBUG -verbose up"
I always retry with the sequence:

1. ctrl+c
2. docker-compose down
3. docker system prune -a
4. docker volume prune

After running these prunes I need to run twice, or else I got the error:

"The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it."

Dockerfile(at /MySQL), there's also a LastDump.sql in this directory

EDIT: Later I deleted this file, and got the same result

```
FROM mysql:8.0.21

RUN chown -R mysql:root /var/lib/mysql/

ENV MYSQL_DATABASE=Olimpo
ENV MYSQL_USER=admin
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD=senha
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=senha

ADD LastDump.sql /etc/mysql/LastDump.sql
RUN sed -i 's/MYSQL_DATABASE/'$MYSQL_DATABASE'/g' /etc/mysql/LastDump.sql
RUN cp /etc/mysql/LastDump.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d

EXPOSE 3306
```

docker-compose.yml(at / main folder)

```
version: "3.8"

# Define services
services:
  # Database Service (Mysql)
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.21
    container_name: mysqlDB
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --init-file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Olimpo
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: senha
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: senha
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      # next line is commented doesn't run with it
      #- ./MySQL/LastDump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - backend

# Volumes
volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  backend:
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seem to be the parameter in the command of your yml file. It worked in my machine when I took it out.

Change from `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password --init-file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` to command: `command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password`

Fixed file is below:

```
# Define services
services:
  # Database Service (Mysql)
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:8.0.21
    container_name: mysqlDB
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: Olimpo
      MYSQL_USER: admin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: senha
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: senha
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
      # next line is commented doesn't run with it
      #- ./MySQL/LastDump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    networks:
      - backend

# Volumes
volumes:
  mysql_data:
    driver: local

# Networks to be created to facilitate communication between containers
networks:
  backend:
```

Answer (score 0):

The mysql dockerfile is useless.

1. Create a folder called mysql-dump with the dump.sql inside.
2. Add the line "USE db_name" to dump.sql

In docker-compose.yml:

3. remove "--init-file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/"
4. add the line in volumes "- ./mysql-dump:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"